# searching for on screen tutorial javascript library

Tags: javascript

I once stumbled upon a javascript library which is used to create interactive on screen tutorials which we may find on many games. I cannot find that library now. Has anyone heard or seen a library like that?

I need it to help new users to learn how to use our site.

Sincerely

EDIT: I was actually looking for a component to guide new users to perform main site operations, much like the initial start guides in social games (click this, type that, press this; kudos you have sent am email.)

I've found one candidate: https://www.redcritterguide.com

Comment: Tourist.js seems leaner

Answer (score 0):

Try [CodePlayer](http://thecodeplayer.com/).

It's a "code recorder" maybe you can use it to record sessions for your users.

Comment: sorry but it is not what I'm looking for. my users have no knowledge of javascript or html.